# TensorflowJS: how to reset input/output shapes for pretrained model in TFJS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

For the [pre-trained model in python](https://github.com/HasnainRaz/Fast-SRGAN/blob/master/models/generator.h5) we can reset input/output shapes:

```
from tensorflow import keras

# Load the model
model = keras.models.load_model('models/generator.h5')

# Define arbitrary spatial dims, and 3 channels.
inputs = keras.Input((None, None, 3))

# Trace out the graph using the input:
outputs = model(inputs)

# Override the model:
model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

[The source code](https://github.com/HasnainRaz/Fast-SRGAN)

I'm trying to do the same in TFJS:

```
 // Load the model
 this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/assets/fast_srgan/model.json');

 // Define arbitrary spatial dims, and 3 channels.
 const inputs = tf.layers.input({shape: [null, null, 3]});
 
 // Trace out the graph using the input.
 const outputs = this.model.apply(inputs) as tf.SymbolicTensor;

 // Override the model.
 this.model = tf.model({inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs});
```

TFJS does not support one of the layers in the model:

```
 ...

 u = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(layer_input)
 u = tf.nn.depth_to_space(u, 2) # <- TFJS does not support this layer
 u = keras.layers.PReLU(shared_axes=[1, 2])(u)

 ...
```

I wrote my own:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

 export class DepthToSpace extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor() {
        super({});
    }

    computeOutputShape(shape: Array<number>) {
        // I think the issue is here
        // because the error occurs during initialization of the model
        return [null, ...shape.slice(1, 3).map(x => x * 2), 32];
    }

    call(input): tf.Tensor {
        const result = tf.depthToSpace(input[0], 2);
        return result;
    }

    static get className() {
        return 'TensorFlowOpLayer';
    }
}
```

Using the model:

```
 tf.tidy(() => {
     let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(this.imgLr.nativeElement, 3);

     img = tf.div(img, 255);
     img = tf.expandDims(img, 0);

     let sr = this.model.predict(img) as tf.Tensor;

     sr = tf.mul(tf.div(tf.add(sr, 1), 2), 255).arraySync()[0];

     tf.browser.toPixels(sr as tf.Tensor3D, this.imgSrCanvas.nativeElement);
 });
```

but I get the error:

> Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer p_re_lu: expected axis 1 of input shape to have value 96 but got shape 1,128,128,32.

The pre-trained model was trained with 96x96 pixels images. If I use the 96x96 image, it works. But if I try to use other sizes (for example 128x128), It doesn't work. In python, we can easily reset input/output shapes. Why it doesn't work in JS?

Answer (score 1):

To define a new model from the layers of the previous model, you need to use `tf.model`

```
this.model = tf.model({inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs});
```

Comment: Thanks, man! But I still have the same error:
Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer p_re_lu: expected axis 1 of input shape to have value 96 but got shape 1,128,128,32.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug this class:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

 export class DepthToSpace extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor() {
        super({});
    }

    computeOutputShape(shape: Array<number>) {
        return [null, ...shape.slice(1, 3).map(x => x * 2), 32];
    }

    call(input): tf.Tensor {
        const result = tf.depthToSpace(input[0], 2);
        return result;
    }

    static get className() {
        return 'TensorFlowOpLayer';
    }
}
```

and saw: when I do not try to rewrite the size, the `computeOutputShape`, method works only twice, and it works 4 times when I try to reset inputs/outputs. Well, then I opened the model's JSON file and changed inputs from [null, 96, 96, 32] to [null, 128, 128, 32] and removed these lines:

```
 // Define arbitrary spatial dims, and 3 channels.
 const inputs = tf.layers.input({shape: [null, null, 3]});
 
 // Trace out the graph using the input.
 const outputs = this.model.apply(inputs) as tf.SymbolicTensor;

 // Override the model.
 this.model = tf.model({inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs});
```

And now it works with 128x128 images. It looks like the piece of code above, adds the layers instead of rewriting them.